# floating point zero and log

Tags: python-3.x, floating-point

My function receives a float, and I try to catch zero before there is a problem, but it is not working. It hangs here:

```
exp = -math.ceil(math.log(v, 2))
def logfun(v):
    if v < 0:
        v = -v
    if int(v) == 0:
        exp = 0
    if v >= 1:
        exp = math.floor(math.log(v, 2))
    if v < 1:
        exp = -math.ceil(math.log(v, 2))
    return(exp)

logfun(0.0)
```

> ValueError: math domain error

Comment: The `if int(v) == 0:` case doesn't stop any of the other cases from triggering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You write:

```
if v < 1:
    exp = -math.ceil(math.log(v, 2))
```

So that means that if `v` is `0`, then this body will fire. Since it is not an `elif`, this will thus not have much effect.

You can use `elif`s, or immediately `return 0` in case `int(v) == 0`, for instance:

```
def logfun(v):
    if v < 0:
        v = -v
    if int(v) == 0:
        return 0
    if v >= 1:
        return math.floor(math.log(v, 2))
    if v < 1:
        return -math.ceil(math.log(v, 2))
```

That being said, if `v < 1`, it means that `int(v) == 0` here, so you can *omit  that case*. Making it:

```
def logfun(v):
    if v < 0:
        v = -v
    if int(v) == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return math.floor(math.log(v, 2))
```